# Inserting Ooxml - Unsupported elements in Word Online

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I've been attempting to insert OOXML into the body content of word documents via the office-js `insertOoXML()` in Word Online. When I use documents which contain TOA or TOC, I get this error:

> RichApi.Error: The action isn’t supported by Word in a browser. Check
>   the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.
>       at new c (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:293287)
>       at b.f.processRequestExecutorResponseMessage (https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:354186)
>       at https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-web-16.00.js:24:352291

As I understand, OfficeJS doesn't support TOA and TOC in Word Online. I've also noticed that I cannot remove them in Word Online.

What other elements are not supported in Word Online by OfficeJS? 
Can I insert OOXML, which contain this unsupported elements, into empty document?

Comment: The list is long, and constantly changing, depending on what Word Online supports at any given point. Rule-of-thumb: anything that can't be used in the Word Online API by a user. Some examples: any content control type except rich text; Hidden text. Headers and footers are problematic. The list goes on...